# Laravel5 Json get file contents

Tags: json, laravel, file-get-contents

I'm using `Laravel-5` right now and I've just created a `JSON` file called test(test.json). My question is:

1. Where should I put my JSON file?
2. How can I use file_get_contents and point to that one file I wanted?

This is what I've tried which is obviously wrong:

```
$string = file_get_contents("../json/test.json");   
$json_file = json_decode($string, true);
```

Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can store it in your storage folder in Laravel:

```
$path = storage_path() . "/json/${filename}.json"; // ie: /var/www/laravel/app/storage/json/filename.json

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true);
```